# Making Android app "remember" data, and saving it on exit

Tags: java, android

I am completely new to android, I've learnt it from a course on Android Developers, also I've never learnt Java, only C#. So, I've made a simple app that has some features, and one of them is increasing a number with every tap on a ImageButton and showing it in a TextView. I want the app to store the number, and never reset it to default value. It happens when I close it, or just minimise it with the home button.

So, I have a method, that increases the number, and shows it in the TextView:

```
public void Increase(View view);
{
myNumber += 1;
counter.SetText(String.valueOf(myNumber));
}
```

And I want myNumber to be kept when the app is minimised or closed, and restored and set as the text for the counter TextView. I've tried learning this by myself, but it only crashed my app when I turned it on.

Comment: Use sharedPreferences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save using sharedPreferences:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("myNumber", myNumber);
    editor.commit();
```

To read from sharedPreferences:

```
    myNumber = preferences.getInt("myNumber", 0);
```

Comment: I've tried that earlier, and it didn't work, but you explained it very clearly and it works. Thank you